# Закругление трех краев ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

Нужно закруглить картинку таким образом, чтобы после загрузки картинка имела такую же форму, как и во время загрузки(см. прикрепленную фотографию)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать грамотно. Заранее благодарю за помощь!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**XML ImageView:**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_incoming_image_message"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/message_incoming_bubble_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/message_incoming_bubble_margin_right"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/messageUserAvatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/messageUserAvatar" />
```

**shape_incoming_image_message:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/message_bubble_corners_radius"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/message_bubble_corners_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/message_bubble_corners_radius" />

    <solid android:color="@color/white_four" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Вы изображения через Picasso подгружаете или через другую библиотеку?

Comment: через другую, через universal image loader

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал вот так:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/message_bubble_corners_radius"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/message_bubble_corners_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/message_bubble_corners_radius" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

Устанавливаем `shape` на форграунд:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

imageView.setImageDrawable(yourImage);
imageView.setForeground(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame_incoming_image_message, null);
```

Comment: getDrawable is deprecated

Comment: @ВладСапожников подправил

Comment: у метода setForeground минимальное API 23 
У меня же 19(
Может есть еще какие нибудь идеи?

Comment: И почему transparent в shape?

Comment: Решение найдено, спасибо за ответы

Comment: @ВладСапожников, если api 19 то можно установить картинку бэкграундом, а shape - основным изображением.